# Only keep column values if they equal a certain value or if they are in a row between this value (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter out rows that do not equal a certain number OR do not have that number in the row before and/or after.

For explanation an example. I have the following dataframe:

```
df_test= pd.DataFrame()
df_test= df_test.assign(group='')
df_test.group= [3,3,5,3,1,3,4,1,1,1,5,3,1,1,3,6,7]


    group
0       3
1       3
2       5
3       3
4       1
5       3
6       4
7       1
8       1
9       1
10      5
11      3
12      1
13      1
14      3
15      6
16      7
```

I want to filter out all values, which do not equal `3`, except `1`: if `1` is in a row where `3` is before and/or after.

The end result would look like this:

```
   group
0      3
1      3
2      3
3      1
4      3
5      3
6      1
7      1
8      3
```

I tried it with

```
df_test[(df_test.group == 1) | (df_test.group==3)]
```

But obviously this keeps all the `1` and not only the ones framed by `3`.

Any help highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare by `==` and chain by `&` shifted Series with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), last chain 3 masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m1 = df_test['group'].eq(1)
m2 = df_test['group'].eq(3)
m3 = m1 & df_test['group'].shift(-1).eq(3)
m4 = m1 & df_test['group'].shift().eq(3)

df_test = df_test[m2|m3|m4]
print (df_test)
    group
0       3
1       3
3       3
4       1
5       3
11      3
12      1
13      1
14      3
```